# What does this line do (uniques) in dataframes

Tags: pandas

can someone help me understand this line. Thanks in advance

```
uniques = data.apply(lambda x: [x.unique])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the syntax that you're looking for is `data.apply(lambda x: [x.unique()])`. If so, then it outputs a DataFrame with a single row. Each element is a list containing the unique elements in that column. An example:-

```
In [14]: data.head()
Out[14]: 
   ipip  wage1992  prtyid     ideol  gender
1     3  0.614226     7.0  5.000000       1
2     4  0.674754     5.0  5.000000       1
3     4  0.267990     7.0  6.000000       1
4     1  0.261490     1.0  4.000000       1
5     3  0.109723     2.0  1.760314       1

In [15]: data.apply(lambda x: [x.unique()])
Out[15]: 
              ipip  ...  gender
0  [3, 4, 1, 5, 2]  ...  [1, 0]

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```

As an example, the `gender` column contains two unique values, 1 and 0.